# StackoverFlowException When creating ZipArchive from within ZipArchive

Tags: c#, zip, c#-ziparchive

I am attempting to recursively parse through a zip folder and any zip folders inside it to collect files using the following code:

```
    private IList<IFile> _getFilesFromZip(ZipArchive zipArchive)
    {
        var returnFiles = new List<IFile>();
        foreach (var zippedFile in zipArchive.Entries)
        {
            var name = zippedFile.Name;
            var type = Path.GetExtension(zippedFile.Name).Replace(".", "");

            if (type == "zip")
            {
                var innerZipArchive = new ZipArchive(zippedFile.Open(), ZipArchiveMode.Read);
                returnFiles.AddRange(_getConversionFilesFromZip(zipArchive));
            }
            else
            { ...
```

> var innerZipArchive = new ZipArchive(zippedFile.Open(), ZipArchiveMode.Read);

Throws a StackOverflow exception no matter how small the files.

How can I create a zipArchive from the ZipArchiveEntry of the first ZipArchive?

Comment: did you mean tot pass `innerZipArchive` to the innermost `_getConversionFilesFromZip` ?

Comment: @MarcGravell yes. however I never make it there due to the exception

Comment: and can we reasonably assume that the zip itself is not malicious? it isn't a [zip bomb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_bomb), etc?

Comment: `top 0.01% overall` ain't going to contribute to make a zip bomb!

Comment: Using the corrected code you have posted here (and assuming that `_getConversionFilesFromZip` is basically doing the same thing as `_getFilesFromZip`), the code works for me.  I can load up a full list of files within a zip file including zipped files which are inside of another zip file.  Can you post the rest of the code including the function `_getConversionFilesFromZip`? Have you executed the code after the correction to pass `innerZipArchive` to the inner function call?

Comment: @MarcGravell turns out I'm just silly. I didn't realize that the exception was being thrown on the first recursion rather than the first pass. changing to innerZipArchive fixed. Thanks Rubber Ducks!

Comment: @jth41 thanks for getting back to me :) also... ***does happy dance at nailing it***